# Flutter runs locally but Testflight build crashes on swift_getObjectType

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

My flutter app deploys successfully on android. It also works fine when i run it on my physical iphone and emulator using Xcode. It however fails to open when deployed to Testflight. I get the following error. I have tried to regenerate the ios folder. And also cleared all caches.

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 1C0A2576-B529-41E6-9CB3-02D939119209
Beta Identifier:     ECFBB799-6DDF-47B3-8FEA-70B5086F67B4
Hardware Model:      iPhone14,3
Process:             Runner [639]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4997CA6E-ED75-4639-AAD4-393BB5E4CF64/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.streetstreams.brorno
Version:             8.9 (89)
AppStoreTools:       15A240a
AppVariant:          1:iPhone14,3:17
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.streetstreams.brorno [866]

Date/Time:           2023-09-29 21:34:45.0428 +0000
Launch Time:         2023-09-29 21:34:44.8921 +0000
OS Version:          iPhone OS 17.0 (21A329)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    3.06.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
VM Region Info: 0 is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 4362600448
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      __TEXT                   104080000-104084000 [   16K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  ...er.app/Runner
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [639]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libswiftCore.dylib                     0x1948ac3ec swift_getObjectType + 40
1   audioplayers_darwin                    0x108d6cb90 static SwiftAudioplayersDarwinPlugin.register(with:) + 60
2   audioplayers_darwin                    0x108d6ce20 @objc static SwiftAudioplayersDarwinPlugin.register(with:) + 56
3   audioplayers_darwin                    0x108d665f0 +[AudioplayersDarwinPlugin registerWithRegistrar:] + 72
4   Runner                                 0x104086d6c +[GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:] + 116
5   Runner                                 0x104087728 AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 212
6   Runner                                 0x104087bc8 @objc AppDelegate.application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) + 196
7   UIKitCore                              0x19d43c1d8 -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 320
8   UIKitCore                              0x19d43b340 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 2856
9   UIKitCore                              0x19d43a324 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 856
10  UIKitCore                              0x19d439f70 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 132
11  UIKitCore                              0x19d3b69dc _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 112
12  UIKitCore                              0x19d43df00 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216
13  UIKitCore                              0x19d362e40 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 332
14  UIKitCore                              0x19d361848 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 608
15  UIKitCore                              0x19d3611b0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 248
16  UIKitCore                              0x19d361080 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 148
17  UIKitCore                              0x19d360f88 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:fromCurrentState:actions:completion:] + 736
18  UIKitCore                              0x19d360810 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContextAndCompletion + 224
19  UIKitCore                              0x19d3604c0 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 316
20  UIKitCore                              0x19d6df8d0 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.225 + 612
21  UIKitCore                              0x19d35f644 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 216
22  UIKitCore                              0x19d35f4b4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 244
23  UIKitCore                              0x19d47a428 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 508
24  UIKitCore                              0x19d47a1c0 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 288
25  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b3124aa8 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 324
26  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b3124944 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.108 + 280
27  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b31235a8 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 168
28  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b312f360 __92-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createSceneWithIdentity:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 352
29  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2f43300 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
30  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1a2f46d48 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 284
31  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b311f9ec __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 52
32  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b311f96c -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 240
33  FrontBoardServices                     0x1b311f844 -[FBSMainRunLoopSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
34  CoreFoundation                         0x19b04cacc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
35  CoreFoundation                         0x19b04bd48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 176
36  CoreFoundation                         0x19b04a55c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 340
37  CoreFoundation                         0x19b049238 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
38  CoreFoundation                         0x19b048e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 608
39  GraphicsServices                       0x1ddb055ec GSEventRunModal + 164
40  UIKitCore                              0x19d457350 -[UIApplication _run] + 888
41  UIKitCore                              0x19d45698c UIApplicationMain + 340
42  Runner                                 0x104087d40 main + 64
43  dyld                                   0x1bd82bd44 start + 2104
```

Have tried to regenerate the ios folder but issue remains same.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/1251

Comment: @jraufeisen I assumed too that this was a problem with Audioplayers. But even when i remove Audioplayers from my pubspec.yaml and rebuild, issue occurs with another plugin. Also this problem does not occur when i build run locally in debug or release. Issue occurs only when i deploy to Testflight.